# Very strange Google Apps Script behavior

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am seeing some very strange behavior with Google Apps Script. All I am trying to do is parse some rows in my sheet and if for any row, if the date is > 1/1/1999 then add a dropdown which pre populates some Error Value. The strange behavior here is that this always populates the dropdown one row above the row which satisfies the date check condition. So for example if row #5 satisfies the condition, the dropdown is populated in row #4. Not sure why this is happening. I also tried to do this

```
var range = sheet.getRange(i+1, 14);
```

but that doesn't seem to show anything on the screen. I am unable to understand this strange behavior. Any help will be appreciated.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];

var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
var values = dataRange.getDisplayValues();

for (var i = rowNum; i < values.length; i++) {

if (new Date(values[i][9]).getTime() > new Date('1/1/1999').getTime()){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(values[i][2]);

  var range = sheet.getRange(i, 14);
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(['Error Value'], true).build();
  range.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

Comment: The code isn't complete, rowNum is not defined.

Comment: I only posted what's relevant here. rowNum is defined.

Comment: See guidelines require a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Use

`var range = sheet.getRange(Number(i)+1, 14);`

When you are using i+1 and when i=20, i+1 will become 201 and you will not seeing any visible difference on the screen. row 201 will be far down your screen.

In JavaScript, numbers and strings will occasionally behave in ways you might not expect. It is always good to take precaution before doing operation on variables.

Also read https://autotelicum.github.io/Smooth-CoffeeScript/literate/js-intro.html#operations-on-numbers-strings

Comment: I may have tried that out at some point. It didn't work. I tried it again and it doesn't work. I see no dropdown in my Google Sheet.

Comment: Also if I can read the right date using values[i][9]).getTime() I don't understand why I would need to do a +1 to get a handle of the same row. Something doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0):

Your data validation is set to null. It should be `Range.setDataValidation(rule)`

that is why you dont see a dropdown box.
This function

`Range.getDisplayValues()`

Returns an array and index of an array starts at 0. However, in a spreadsheet the row index starts at 1. So you need to add 1 to convert array index to a row index. Use the following to get the correct range

`Sheet.getRange(i+1,14)`

Comment: You are correct the code I posted here is wrong and had null but I had tested with rule.

Comment: Well then my friend I am at a loss as to why it is not working. Is it possible for you to share a spreadsheet with some mock data? So I can try to troubleshoot it

Comment: I actually figured out the issue. It was something else that was overwriting the value. I am trying to figure out how to close the issue. Thanks for taking the time to look at it!